# how to print selected dropdown list options plus text field when using js only?

Tags: javascript, dropdown

Good afternoon Stackoverflow folks,

I have the following javascript code, and I want to pass the dorpdown option + text filed into one singe string:
Example
"Mr. John"
"Mrs. Johna"
The number of members has to be defined before filling out.

Is there a way of doing this with html? (this is one field of an html form)
or creating a second function showFields()

I am trying with jQuery but till now I havent succeeded.

```
function addFields() {
    var number = document.getElementById('member').value;
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var optionsSelect = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Mr'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Mrs'
        }
    ];
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var select = document.createElement('select');
        for (var j = 0; j < optionsSelect.length; j++) {
            var options = document.createElement('option');
            options.value = optionsSelect[j].id;
            options.text = optionsSelect[j].title;
            select.appendChild(options);
        }
        container.appendChild(select);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' -> Name ' + (i + 1)));
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}

      <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of  members: (max. 10)<br />
      <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
      <div id="container"/>
```

Code can be tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cxLot0ae/)

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: can you clean your code up abit its hard to parse like this.

Comment: sorry about that and thanks for the corrections

Comment: can you explain what you mean aswell not clear, so when you've filled it out you just want a string of the results ?

Comment: hi Joe, yes I want to, after filling out, submit the lines [select] [text] both fields as a string, for instance Mr. John. The idea is to submit all fields in one single column (text field) in the DB.

Comment: i mean i can show you how to do that but if you're saving to db why not save as seperate entries?

Comment: @JoeWarner yes I know, sounds weird. due to limited db and that cannot be changed right now unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is reduce how to take a data set and 'reduce' it into one thing.

another thing to look into is template literals to make things cleaner makes constructing strings very easy.

I've also done it so it maps to an array and i'd suggest going down this route.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
const optionsSelect = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Mr'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Mrs'
  }
];

function getResults() {
  const { selects, inputs } = getInputs();

  return selects.reduce((acc, select, i) => {
    const { title, name } = getValuesFromElements(select, inputs[i]);
    
    return (title && name) ? `${acc} ${title}. ${name}` : acc;
  }, '');
}

function getResultsAsArray() {
  const { selects, inputs } = getInputs();
  
  const getFieldValues = (select, i) => {
    const { title, name } = getValuesFromElements(select, inputs[i]);
    
    return (title && name) ? `${title}. ${name}` : '';
  };

  return selects.map(getFieldValues).filter(Boolean);
}

function getValuesFromElements(select, {value: name}) {
  const { title } = optionsSelect[select.value - 1];

  return {title, name};
}

function getContainerElements(query) {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`#container > ${query}`));
}

function getInputs() {
  const selects = getContainerElements('select');
  const inputs = getContainerElements('input');

  return {
    selects,
    inputs
  }
}


function addFields() {
  const { value: number } = document.getElementById('member');
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    const select = document.createElement('select');
    for (let j = 0; j < optionsSelect.length; j++) {
      const options = document.createElement('option');
      options.value = optionsSelect[j].id;
      options.text = optionsSelect[j].title;
      select.appendChild(options);
    }
    container.appendChild(select);
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' -> Name ' + (i + 1)));
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
<a href="#" onclick="console.log(getResults())">Log results</a>
<a href="#" onclick="console.log(getResultsAsArray())">Log results as array</a>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I meant! Charm  solution with a very and clean code. Appreciate your time and explanation.

Comment: Hi Joe, maybe you can help with the following:   In the getResults function I added msgs = (title && name) ? `${acc} ${title}. ${name}` : acc; document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = msgs;   Now I use php as backend and want to pass the result  <div id="output"></div> to a php variable.

Comment: what do you mean? `$container = "<div id="container"></div>"`

Comment: Nevermind! I found the error in my code. Everything working normal with <?php $msgs = "<div id='output'></div>";
echo $msgs;
?>  Thank you very much once again!!!

Comment: @Lango no problem :)

Comment: just credited you for my next question :) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407982/saving-a-div-to-mysql-using-js-and-php-possible)